# How can I do a loop in the loop i want to do a exit when

Tags: python, turing-lang

I want to do a loop in python and how can i do a exit when?

In Turing what I want is

```
loop
    put " Voulez vous jouer au 6-49 si oui entrez 'commencer' et n'oubliez pas qu'une "
    put " partie coute 3$ " ..
    color (green)
    get word
    color (black)

    %Je clear l'ecrant
    cls
    put " Chargement en cour."
    delay (500)
    cls
    put " Chargement en cour.."
    delay (500)
    cls
    put " Chargement en cour..."
    delay (500)
    cls

    %Je fais certain que le joueur a ecrit commencer
    %Si il entre quelque choses d'autre que commencer le programme ne commence pas il demander de entre le mot commencer

    exit when word = "commencer"
end loop
```

Now I need to do in Python but I don't know how to do that can someone help me out plzzz????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the semantics of the Turing code,

```
while True:
    ...
    if word == "commencer":
        break
```

Comment: It not working. That is my code in pycharm:
print(" Bienvenue au jeu de lotteries 6-49")
print(" Pour commencer le jeu veuillez entrez ""commencer")
commencer = input()

c = 'commencer'
while True:
    ...
if word == "commencer":
    break

  File "D:/Python/6-49", line 14
    break
    ^
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop

Comment: That sounds like an indentation error; the `if` statement needs to be *in* the body of the loop.

Comment: How I do that? For me Python is all new so I'm not good at all in python

Comment: Thx for your help Chepner